# Slick 3 unique constraint between two keys

Tags: slick-3.0

I have a SQL model

```
create table "model" (
    "id" BIGINT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('venue_id_seq'),
    "description" VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    "prop_a" BIGINT,
    "prop_b" BIGINT,
    unique(prop_a, prop_b)
);
```

Is it possible in the slick schema definition to define this constraint or do we need to handle the exception?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you mean `unique index` on db level. You can define it like here:

```
def idx = index("model_unique", (prop_a, prop_b), unique = true)
```

Obviously you put it into your Slick table definition (aka `Mixed Type`)